# Help identifying tree

Tags: identification

Can someone identify this tree here in central Utah?  I have tried hard to figure it out but have just failed so far.  The lighting wasn't the best for this picture and I'm happy to take some better pictures if it would help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your pictures are great!

Comment: Ryan, welcome to Gardening SE! You are doing us and the site a great favor by taking exactly the kind of pictures you took - overall, closeups of bark, leaves, blooms. And in focus. (Sigh...) Thank you! Let me point you to the [tour] and the [help] for more details about how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some kind of hawthorn. Possibly Crataegus laevigata 'Paul's Scarlet' - https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/93812/Crataegus-laevigata-Paul-s-Scarlet-(d)/Details

Comment: After looking through more pictures of Paul's Scarlet and reading about it, this is almost certainly correct.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It's a popular tree here in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a hawthorn; Crataegus spp. [Hawthorn general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crataegus)

Comment: That appears correct. Thanks.  (I selected the more specific answer saying it's probably a Hawthorn Paul's Scarlet.)